# what is wrong with python my python code in *args?

Tags: python

can anyone can help me I was expected that the output is 625 but it shows the output is zero

```
    def add(*args):
    sum = 0
    for i in args:
        sum *= i
    return sum

print(add(5, 5, 5, 5))
```

Comment: Anything multiplied by zero is zero…

Comment: and a side note - don't use `sum` as name, it is a built-in function, not to mention it is also misleading.

Comment: Consider using a less deceptive name than `add`.

Comment: 1) `sum` should not be used as it's overwriting the built-in. 2) Instead, a more accurate variable `product` should be initialised to 1.

Comment: It is a `product`, not a `sum`. It's doing`multiply`, not `add`. Initialise the product with `1`, not `0`. And your first line is not indented properly.

Comment: What do you really want to achive? Do you want to add the values (like the name suggests) or do you want to multiply the values (like your "expected outcome" suggests)? As soon as you know that, keep in mind that in case of multiplication, the neutral value is 1, not 0, and in case of summation, you need to add, not multiply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the value of sum = 0

And, you multiplying the values with 0. Therefore, you are getting no answer.

Change this line

```
sum = 0
```

To:-

```
sum = 1
```

Thank You.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that's just a copy-paste formatting error and has nothing to do with the problem the OP has. Otherwise, python would throw an error and not just print 0.

Comment: Also, this still prints `0`.

Comment: Sorry! I regret for my mistake.

Comment: Got the solution!

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the sum variable to 0, an in the for loop you are multiplying the sum with i. Any number multiplied with 0 is 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def multiply(*args):
...     result = 1
...     for i in args:
...             result *= i
...     return result
...
>>> print(multiply(5,5,5,5))
625
```

**Or** rather if you wanted to add

```
>>> def add(*args):
...     result = 0
...     for i in args:
...             result += i
...     return result
...
>>> print(add(5,5,5,5))
20
```

**Or** rather do this pythonic way

```
>>> mul = lambda x,y: x*y
>>> functools.reduce(mul, [5,5,5,5])
625
```

**Or** rather single liner

```
>>> functools.reduce(lambda x,y : x*y, [5,5,5,5])
625
>>> functools.reduce(lambda x,y : x+y, [5,5,5,5])
20
```

- Please define your function to have meaningful names.
- Don't use inbuilt names like "sum"
- Have meaningful variable names

Answer (score 1):

First of all, anything multiplied by zero is zero. Therefore if you want to multiply the numbers received, you need to change `sum = 0` to `sum = 1`.

Secondly, don't use `sum` as a variable or function name, as it is a built-in function in python. It is also misleading as you want your function to multiply the given args (and therefore also don't call the function `add`). To achieve a readable code, you should have meaningful variable and function names.

Also, your first line isn't indented correctly. You can read about python indentation [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

Putting it all together:

```
def multiply(*args):
    multiplication = 1
    for i in args:
        multiplication *= i

    return multiplication

print(multiply(5, 5, 5, 5))
```

Output:

```
625
```